# Maintaining aspect ratio of image inside a square html element

Tags: html, css

This is a notoriously difficult problem in html/css, but I'm asking anyway. I am looking for a concrete response, not a philosophical one.

If in the html file below I use only "width: 64px;", the images appear in the correct aspect ratio, but the list items are not uniformly spaced.

If I use "width: 64px; height: 64px;", the item separation is correct, but the images have the wrong aspect ratio.

A common solution is to wrap the images within a square. I'd like to avoid this.

> ```
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <style type = "text/css"> 
>             img {
>             width: 64px;
>             }
>         </style> 
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <ul>
>             <li>
>                 <a href="foo.html">
>                     <img align="middle" style="bulletIcon" src="image1.svg"/>
>                     Foo
>                 </a>
>             </li>
>             <li>
>                 <a href="bar.html">
>                     <img align="middle" style="bulletIcon" src="image2.svg"/>
>                     Foo
>                 </a>
>             </li>
>             <li>
>                 <a href="bar.html">
>                     <img align="middle" style="bulletIcon" src="image2.svg"/>
>                     Foo
>                 </a>
>             </li>
>             <li>
>                 <a href="foo.html">
>                     <img align="middle" style="bulletIcon" src="image1.svg"/>
>                     Foo
>                 </a>
>             </li>
>         </ul>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

Here are the two images. They are here svg for completeness, but the actual problem is indeed harder because they are jpg/png (and so I can't just play with the svg viewbox, which is a bad solution anyway).

Here is image1.svg

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>      width="100" height="200"
>      viewBox="0 0 100 200"
>      version="1.1">
> <g>
>     <path d="M 10 10 L 90 10 L 90 190 L 10 190 z"
>           fill="cyan" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" />
> </g>
> </svg>
> ```

and now image2.svg

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>      width="200" height="100"
>      viewBox="0 0 200 100"
>      version="1.1">
> <g>
>     <path d="M 10 10 L 190 10 L 190 90 L 10 90 z"
>           fill="cyan" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" />
> </g>
> </svg>
> ```

Comment: I'm confused about the exact end result you are looking for? An evenly spaced grid of images, but with different aspect ratios?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need IE7 support, I'd suggest you use table-row / table-cell: http://jsfiddle.net/vRkgs/

```
li {
    display:table-row;
}
li a {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Turning the list items into a clickable area the same height as the image looks quite bad. It's also a bit of a trap for accidental clicking.